# While accessing the assembly in otherAppdomain ,how to reflect the changes done in assembly in Other appdomain Referred

Tags: c#

I am accessing one assembly in other application by loading that assembly in Another Appdomain,its working fine.

My Question is : If I make changes in the Assembly and build it,the changes are not getting reflected in the application where I have created the another appdomain for accessing it unless i build the application .

Plz let me know how can I access the assembly in this case without building the application.

Thanks,
Gagan dhamija

Answer (score 1):

You have to first unload the appdomain, then recreate it, and load the updated assembly.

Comment: This not entirely right, I've run into problems especially with managed DLLs invoking native dlls. Particularly with old dll remaining resident which results in noticeable 'memory leak' looking problem.

Comment: @ivo s: If you are not careful, of course you will run into problems, notably assemblies/types jumping over the appdomain boundary, which makes unloading impossible. But that is a completely different problem.

Comment: @leppie: this is true if don't know what you are doing you can spend days to decide to change the approach. I'd bet that in practice the author will run into difficulties.

Comment: @ivo s: I have wasted weeks on understanding this when I started C#  :)  Very much a design decision that needs to be kept in consideration at all times (unless you wanna end up create wrappers for everything, like I did years back).

Comment: @leppie: I have also wasted weeks:) Just that the author doesn't look like can do it. There is a few possible exact duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unload+appdomain which can give quite a bit of detail on how to do it but the author didn't find them so I'm thinking it's not too good for his case.

Comment: @ivo s: No denying that it is an excellent learning experience once you do understand it :)

Comment: @leppie: Excellent learning experience for sure but can make you age quickly.

Comment: @ivo s: I was old when I started coding ;P  (26 or 27, now almost 36)

Comment: @leppie: :) That's not too old. I'm currently between 15% to 25% younger then you but am afraid to give my exact age:) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: hahaha.... I tried both the ways ,still not working.Well plz you both dont fight .Iam new in C# just have 1year exp.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDomain lAppDomain = null;
AppDomainManager appDomainManager = new AppDomainManager();

AppDomainSetup lDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
lDomainSetup.ApplicationName = "OtherAppDomain";
lDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
lDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath = "bin";
lDomainSetup.CachePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "cache\\");
lDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
lDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories = @"C:\Users\gagan.dhamija\Desktop\My project\MainClass\MainClass\bin\Debug\MainClass.dll";
lAppDomain = appDomainManager.CreateDomain("OtherDomain", null, lDomainSetup);

lAppDomain.Load("MainClass");
lAppDomain.InitializeLifetimeService();

Assembly[] CollectionAssembly = lAppDomain.GetAssemblies();

foreach (Assembly assembly in CollectionAssembly)
{
    if (assembly.FullName == "MainClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
        Exportedvalues = GetAllExportedTypes(assembly);
}

MessageBox.Show("Loaded Assembly succesfully");
```

this is what I'm using, but not reflecting the changes

Comment: try to change to lDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories = @"C:\Users\gagan.dhamija\Desktop\My project\MainClass\MainClass\bin\Debug";

Comment: some links that may help you http://jdscolam.blogspot.com/2008/01/joys-of-appdomains.html

Comment: You are breaching the appdomain boundary already at `Assembly[] CollectionAssembly = lAppDomain.GetAssemblies();`  Like we discussed, you really need to design your plan first.